# Navigating through UINavigationController ViewControllers on an iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ipad

I have a master detail application. I have several views and I push them into the detailNavigationController. But every time I want to show the views I need to push them again and there are a lot of viewControllers in the detailNavigation controller. Is there a way to navigate to a viewController that's already been pushed to the navigation controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use the `popToViewController:` method.